# Java 8: create new instance of class with generics using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8

I have the following method:

```
public Comparator<T> getComparator()  throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    String className = "some.ClassName";
    Class<Comparator<T>> c = Class.forName(className); // (1)
    return (Comparator<T>) c. newInstance();
}
```

In the line (1) I get this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class <capture#1-of ?> to
>   Class<Comparator<T>>

What's wrong in this code and how should I make an instance of `Comparator<T>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can get so far is

```
public <T> Comparator<T> getComparator()  throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class<? extends Comparator> implementation
        = Class.forName("some.ClassName").asSubclass(Comparator.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Comparator<T> c = implementation.newInstance();
    return c;
}
```

Note that there is still an unchecked operation which is unavoidable. The runtime type token `Comparator.class` produces a `Class<Comparator>` rather than `Class<Comparator<T>>` which reflects the type erasure and implies that you can use it via `asSubclass` to ensure that a `Class` indeed implements `Comparator`, but you can’t ensure that it implements `Comparator<T>` regarding any `<T>`. (Note that this method doesn’t even know what `T` is). Therefore there is still an unchecked conversion of `Comparator` to `Comparator<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the cast:

```
Class<Comparator<T>> c = (Class<Comparator<T>>) Class.forName(className); // (1)
return c.newInstance();
```

Comment: It will work, but it's a java2-style approach. I was looking for java5-style one.

Comment: Also, it generates warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<Comparator<T>>

Comment: @Antonio, what do you mean by "java5-style". `Class.forName()` will return a `Class<?>` object and you **will** need to cast it to whatever you want and make sure the casting will work fine... Because compiler cannot make sure the string "some.ClassName" is the name of a class implementing `Comparator<T>`.

Comment: @Antonio Do you mean something like

String className = "some.ClassName";
Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(className);
Object obj = aClass.newInstance();

return Comparator.class.cast(obj);

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Comparator<T> getComparator() throws Exception {
    String className = "some.ClassName";
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(className); // (1)
    return (Comparator<T>) c. newInstance();
}
```